# How to choose a folder location for xip temp

Tags: file, terminal, storage, xcode12

I have a xip file called `Xcode_12.3.xip`, and I want to un-xip it into a folder, but I do not have enough space, so I want to change the temp location of xip into a directory on to a folder on my flash drive, but it is always taking up the space on Macintosh HD. How do I change the temp location of xip?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you do not have to.

If you unzip it from an external drive then it will be located in
TemporaryItems

The issue is that it will change location for where the folder called TemporaryItems is placed.

Suggestion for you is to use Disk Drill and do a harddisk scan for files of size larger than 10GB just after expanding the file. Then you can pull it from the temp folder directly into the applications. Archive utility will then fail but you will have succeeded installing XCode in an earlier version.